# Debug Odoo application with Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, odoo

I am setting up a docker development environment for Odoo 15. Making and starting a docker container worked perfectly. Now I am trying to find out how to Debug my code in Pycharm.

I am using Pycharm Professional on a MAC. My Compose file looks like this

```
  web:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: .
    depends_on:
       - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/etc/odoo/data
      - ./dev.conf:/etc/odoo/config/dev.conf
      - ./code/:/etc/odoo/code/
    db:
     image: postgres:13
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_DB=*
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*
       - POSTGRES_USER=*
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
```

My configuration file looks like this:

[DOCKER Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB83V.png)

[DOCKER Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozFhL.png)

[Configuration File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbjXH.png)

A break point stops at the Odoo-bin file but will not stop after that.

I have tried different configurations for the Volumes and tried installing pydev in my development docker to Remote connect. I expected it to stop at one of my break points after triggering an action but it just ran without breaking.